# in need of a random "hot or not" algorithm/solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm working on a "hot or not" type of web application where user will be able to rate some random picture and we want to encourage user to rate by making they own picture submitted showing up more often. Below is the descritpion of what i'm looking for.

1- Need to show the user random picture
2- User with most activity will have a greater chance of there picture showing up
3- Assume a lot of picture, so i'm in need of a efficient solution

What the most effective way of doing this? The only solutions i have at the moment is to keep a master list table with all the picture and when somebody rate i insert a records in that table to add up to they % of showing up and when a user load up the app i load a random 500 picture id in the session with a exclude list for already review/rate picture.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is not a truly random selection, but a weighted selection.  The key will be figuring out how to weight each picture and still have some meaningful randomness in the algorithm.  Your definition of "user activity" will give you the basis for the weight.

Assume that you consider activity to be the number of pictures shown.  Then, for each user, keep this value associated with their account (so you don't have to calculate it each time).  For each picture choose a random number between 0 and 1 and multiply it by the weight for the user who uploaded the picture.  Order the pictures by the resulting value and choose the top 500 pictures to display to that user.  Obviously you can exclude pictures that the user has already rated if you want.  They don't even need to be weighted.

Adjust your weighting criteria -- perhaps you want to make sure that the weights fall within some minimum/maximum range so that all user have some minimum chance of having their pictures selected and no user can dominate the selections.  You may need to tinker with it -- perhaps add or multiply by a constant -- to get the distribution the way you want.  There's undoubtedly a way to derive it using probabilities, but I can't do probabilities this early in the morning.

Comment: So have a list of pictures-to-rate for each user?

Comment: No. Each time a user logins in choose a set of pictures to rate so that you don't have to recalculate on each request.  If you run out of pictures to rate, then you'd have to generate a new set.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd implement this using the Pipeline pattern, coupled with a scoring mechanism.

Begin by extracting all the relevant items and pass them through the pipeline. You may not need to retrieve them from the database every time - since it is going to be (pseudo)random in any case, caching will not be a problem.

In your pipeline, you can register a number of different strategies that can assign or modify an item's score based on different algorithms. Some of these algorithms may assign random scores, while some may assign deterministic scores base on the user's activity, etc.

In the end, you sort the items and pick the ones with the highest score.

This design gives you good separation of concerns: if you need to modify parts of the algorithm, you can add or remove strategies from the pipeline without touching any of the other strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to store each user's activity.  The trick is how to choose the next picture based a weighting - without looking through the entire list of user activities, applying a weighting and then mapping a random number to the list.

One way would be to score/weight all photos based on their respective user's activity and store this alongside each photos.  For each pageview you would filter all photos by randomly generating a 'cut-off' score, then randomly select a photo from the set of photos which have a score higher than the 'cut-off' score.

You would need to tweak the weightings and cut-off scores for this to be effective, but it meets your requirements without the need for storing excessive lists or pre-indexing a large amount of data.